# A Vim command for formatting objects

Tags: vim

Is there an easy shortcut (or plugin) in Vim that can help with formatting code like this:

```
var obj = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    four: 4
};
```

into this?

```
var obj = {
    one    : 1,
    two    : 2,
    three  : 3,
    four   : 4
};
```

Comment: Your best bet is going to be to pipe your buffer into an external filter like http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: The plugin Tabularize will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several align plugins, which could handle this kind of problems very easily:

https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align

https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular

https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align

personally I am using the last one (oldest maybe? ). for your need, I just V select those lines and `<leader>t:` done!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a vim regular expression.  Highlight the lines you can to format with `ctrl-V` (capital `V`) then:

```
:s;\v^(\s*)(\w+)\s*:\s*(\d+,*);\=printf("%s%-7s: %s", submatch(1), submatch(2), submatch(3));g
```

The `:s` will be replaced with `:'<,'>s`, because of visual blockwise mode.